# os._exit() called on another thread does not exit a program

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, exit

I just start a new thread:

```py
self.thread = ThreadedFunc()
self.thread.start()
```

after something happens I want to exit my program so I'm calling `os._exit()`:

```py
os._exit(1)
```

The program still works. Everything is functional and it just looks like the `os._exit()` didn't execute.

Is there a different way to exit a whole program from different thread? How to fix this?

**EDIT:** Added more complete code sample.

```py
self.thread = DownloadThread()
self.thread.data_downloaded.connect(self.on_data_ready)
self.thread.data_progress.connect(self.on_progress_ready)
self.progress_initialized = False
self.thread.start()

class DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread):
    # downloading stuff etc.

    sleep(1)
    subprocess.call(os.getcwd() + "\\another_process.exe")
    sleep(2)
    os._exit(1)
```

***EDIT 2:*** SOLVED! There is a `quit()`, `terminate()` or `exit()` function which just stops the thread. It was that easy. Just look at the docs.

Comment: You should post complete code sample in your question. The code in your question is incomplete. It is hard to guess your issue.

Comment: @hehaoqian Sorry for the late update. I added the more complete code sample hope this helps you help me :p.

Comment: `def DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread):` are you sure?

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh wait I updated it. In code I had 
`class DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread)` I just typed it wrong in here.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `os._exit(1)` works for me.
You should use the standard lib `threading`.

I guess you are using `multiprocessing`, which is a process-based “threading” interface, which uses similar API to `threading`, but creates child process instead of child thread. so `os._exit(1)` only exits child process, not affecting the main process

Also you should ensure you have called `join()` function in the main thread. Otherwise, it is possible that the operating system schedules to run the main thread to the end before starting to do anything in child thread.

sys.exit() does not work because it is the same as raising a SystemExit exception. Raising an exception in thread only exits that thread, rather than the entire process.

Sample code. Tested under ubuntu by `python3 thread.py; echo $?`.
Return code is 1 as expected

```
import os
import sys
import time
import threading
# Python Threading Example for Beginners
# First Method
def greet_them(people):
    for person in people:
        print("Hello Dear " + person + ". How are you?")
        os._exit(1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
# Second Method
def assign_id(people):
    i = 1
    for person in people:
        print("Hey! {}, your id is {}.".format(person, i))
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)

people = ['Richard', 'Dinesh', 'Elrich', 'Gilfoyle', 'Gevin']
t = time.time()
#Created the Threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=greet_them, args=(people,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=assign_id, args=(people,))
#Started the threads
t1.start()
t2.start()
#Joined the threads
t1.join()   # Cannot remove this join() for this example
t2.join()
# Possible to reach here if join() removed
print("I took " + str(time.time() - t))
```

Credit: Sample code is copied and modified from https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-threading-example/

Comment: My sample code works on Windows10 and Ubuntu16, in Python2.7 and Python3.6

Comment: I suggest you to add `print("sth", flush=True)` immediately before `os._exit(1)` to check if the exit function is called.

Comment: @Aspect013 Did you call `join()` method in the main thread? Answer edited to explain why that's needed

Comment: No. I didn't call `join()` in the main thread. Even if I do where do I put the `os._exit()` then? In the main thread or the 2nd thread? Also `os._exit()` works with `print("sth", flush=True` but does not work without it. Why?

Comment: Not joining child thread in main thread has undefined and non-deterministic behavior. Because then it's possible that main thread runs to the end, and exits the program (When main thread exits, the program exists), before running anything inside child thread. Note that it's not guaranteed to happen, happens randomly.  I think `print` has nothing to do with your issue. Magic stuffs happen in program with undefined behavior, especially when there are multiple threads.

Comment: I suggest you to start with a working code sample and see if the problem solves.

Comment: And you should post more code sample in your question. The code in your question is incomplete. It is hard to guess your issue.

Comment: Okay. So I have to do `join()` but do you know how to do `join()` in PyQt 4 (QThread)? I can't find it...

Comment: Any ideas? I have no clue... Can't find it anywhere.